# How to get tear-free rendering with nvidia proprietary?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, awesome, compton

I never experienced tearing before since I was using Ubuntu all the time but recently I have switched to **Arch Linux** with **awesome** as my window manager. Since awesome does not use any composite manager I see these annoying glitches while scrolling the web page. I have installed **compton** and it works but I have some issues with it enabled.

Graphic card: **GeForce GTX 670** with **proprietary** driver (387.34-19)
compton --version: **v0.1_beta2.5**

```
compton --daemon --config /dev/null --backend glx
```

1. Sometimes terminal emulator I use (xfce4-terminal) does not render output until additional keystroke. The issue is described [here](https://github.com/chjj/compton/issues/363), [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1623582) and [here](https://np.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4gtacw/terminal_sometimes_does_not_render_output_until/).
2. The google chrome context menu sometimes flickers.

Nevertheless, it fixes tearing.

```
compton --daemon --config /dev/null --backend xrender
```

This fixes issues described above but tearing itself.

```
compton --daemon --config /dev/null --backend xr_glx_hybrid
```

This fixes issue #1 and tearing but issue #2. Moreover, screen flush starts to appear randomly. I have found that I can fix issue #2 by passing `--fading` option but the latter one is still present.

So, `xrender` works pretty well since it does not produce new bugs but I do not think it is good decision to investigate to when I have gpu with proprietary drivers. It seems that `compton` is a bunch of hacks and tricks, I am tired to make it work properly. I have tried `xcompmgr` and saw no desired effect - there was tearing during scrolling.

Fortunately, there is another solution to make desktop tear-free using `ForceCompositionPipeline=On`. I have configured my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-nvidia.conf` properly and everything is perfect except input latency. The mouse pointer has become less responsiveness, more smoothed. Perhaps, the keyboard is too but I am not sure (I mean, it takes more time to print the key I have pressed).

I am looking for any possibility to get rid of tearing. New composite managers as well as proper `compton` options are acceptable but the solution for latter issue is preferable since I do not actually need all these features like shadow or fading provided by compositors.

Comment: Turn on VSync?  Tearing is usually an artifact of a new frame being drawn to the display before the previous frame has been completely drawn.  VSync forced one frame to be drawn for each frame the display is physically prepared to render.

Comment: Which `backend` should I use?

Comment: @Evgeniy your question already states that you're using the nvidia proprietary drivers.  So, no need to ask follow-up question in comments.  You should be able to open `nvidia-settings` and apply the suggestions from @DopeGhoti

Comment: I had no installed `nvidia-settings` gui. I have installed it, the option `Sync to VBlank` is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve these issues. As I said, to fix issue #2, pass `--fading` option. To increase animation speed or turn it off (set 1) you can pass `--fade-in-step` and `--fade-out-step` options. I had screen flush when there was `xr_glx_hybrid` as backend, so `glx` is preferable. And I do not know why but I have found that options `--xrender-sync` and `--xrender-sync-fence` fix issue #1. Maybe `compton` uses `xrender` when `glx` fails...

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but thanks a lot for your answer.

You can also add those options in the config file for a more repeatable setup.

```
backend = "xr_glx_hybrid";
fading = true;
fade-in-step = 0.03; # Choose your own value here
fade-out-step = 0.03; # Same as above
xrender-sync-fence = true;
```